# How point to other link after login

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, user-interface, joomla

I'm writing to ask you for some help.

In my joomla 5 site, I created two homepages

1. homepage1 (I set guest i.e. after logging in this page is no longer seen)
2. homepage 2 (I set registered, and it is the one that users must see after logging in)

Now, beyond the creation of the home pages, this is just to make you understand, I need

the logo after login not to point to [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com) but to [www.domainname.com/hompage2](http://www.domainname.com/hompage2)

Can anyone give me some info on how to proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: You can set the redirect page after login and logout in the login module

Answer (score 0):

Hi Riccardo and thank you for your kind response, in fact that's exactly what I did but when I click on the logo it takes me to the homepage nomedominio.com instead of nomedominio.com/homepage

I created a child template but it didn't help me much because I certainly had to work on php

here is the index.php of the page but I don't know which rule to apply

```html
<?php
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
//for_use

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$input = Factory::getApplication()->input;
$menu = Factory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
$pageclass = $menu !== null ? $menu->getParams()->get('pageclass_sfx', '') : '';
$option   = $input->getCmd('option', '');
$loadoffline = $input->getInt("loadoffline", false);
if ($loadoffline == 1) {
    include_once "offline.php";
    exit();
}
//HtmlHelper::_('bootstrap.framework');
//HtmlHelper::_('bootstrap.tooltip');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>">
<head>
    <jdoc:include type="head"/>
    <?php require 'lib/index_inc.php'; ?>
</head>
<body id='ml_body' class="<?php echo $pageclass . ' '.$option; ?>">
<?php $content->render(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```